# DataNode failing to Start in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, installation, ubuntu-11.04, cloudera

I trying setup Hadoop install on Ubuntu 11.04 and Java 6 sun. I was working with hadoop 0.20.203 rc1 build. I am repeatedly running into an issue on Ubuntu 11.04 with java-6-sun. When I try to start the hadoop, the datanode doesn't start due to "Cannot access storage".

```
2011-12-22 22:09:20,874 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Cannot lock storage /home/hadoop/work/dfs_blk/hadoop. The directory is already locked.
2011-12-22 22:09:20,896 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage /home/hadoop/work/dfs_blk/hadoop. The directory is already locked.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:602)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1437)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1573)
```

I have tried upgrading and downgrading to couple of versions in 0.20 branch from Apache, even cloudera, also deleting and installing hadoop again. But Still I am running into this issue. Typical workarounds such as deleting *.pid files in /tmp directory is also not working. Could anybody point me to solution for this?

Comment: Please format your logs properly the next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I formatted the namenode , the problem was in of the rogue templates for `hdfs-site.xml` that i copy pasted , the `dfs.data.dir` and `dfs.name.dir` pointed to the same directory location resulting  Locked storage error. They should be different directories. Unfortunately, the hadoop documentation is not clear enough in this subtle details.