# hdfs get blocked - Cannot lock storage /home/hduser/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name. The directory is already locked

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

```
ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage /home/hduser/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name. The directory is already locked.
```

Why did this come up ?

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   96G  9.4G   82G  11% /
devtmpfs                 3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.6G  666M  3.0G  19% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.6G  1.4M  3.6G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    3.6G   42M  3.6G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda1                976M   96M  813M  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-var    48G  3.3G   43G   8% /var
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  145G   15G  123G  11% /hom
```

1) I have enough space for datanode.

2) I know once I format namenode that will start working , but why to format I will lose my data.

3) How to solve this problem without formatting namenode.

Comment: Show us the full stacktrace ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613112/datanode-failing-to-start-in-hadoop , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705140/hadoop-datanode-fails-to-start-throwing-org-apache-hadoop-hdfs-server-common-sto

Comment: It is unlikely to be anything to do with the amount of free space you have.

Comment: Have you checked the links @StephenC wrote? Do you have `dfs.data.dir` and `dfs.name.dir` pointing to the same directory? Could you please post the contents of your xml files?